# Icons missing after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, icons

I did the upgrade after the Focal Fossa release on April 23rd, and I found that some icons are missing in Nautilus and other applications. They have been replaced by a "document icon," as you can see in these screenshots:

- [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmmzV.png)
- [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS4jr.png)

I tried reinstalling some packages but no luck: `sudo apt install -f gnome-extra-icons gnome-icon-theme`.

Did someone else found this issue?

Comment: Can you change the icon theme to Yaru which comes with Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Done and fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of the custom theme you are using. Try to use another one and check if the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. And thanks to @Tanvir too. I didn't remember I had a different set of icons configured. I fixed this using the Ubuntu Tweek utility.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on my case with

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```